# How to detect whether a date format is in a list?

Tags: python

I am try to detect whether a list has an ele(s) in or not.
For example:

```
l1 = [['2018-04-16', '2020-04-16', 'ANNOVAR_DATE'],['abcd', 'efgh', 'ANNOVAR_DATE']]
```

and I have a format string:

```
format = "%Y-%m-d"
```

The goal is to find that the first sublist of l1 has date format but the second sublist of l1 doesn't.
I tired to use two for loops, iterate eles and i in the lists and compare i to formate string. If find, return sublist (['2018-04-16', '2020-04-16', 'ANNOVAR_DATE']), skip otherwise.

```
import datetime
format = "%Y-%m-d"
for ele in l1:
   for i in ele:
    #print(i)
    if datetime.datetime.strptime(i, format):
       #print("This is the correct date string format.")
       #return sublist that contains date format
       
    else:
       #print("This is the incorrect date string format. ")
```

However, it always report errors:
ValueError: time data '2018-04-16' does not match format '%Y-%m-d'

Any ideas? If you feel you need more clarification, just comment! Thanks

Comment: There's a typo in the format, it should be: `format = "%Y-%m-%d"`

Comment: I think you want `try:` / `except ValueError:` rather than `if:` / `else:`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you

- fix typo in `format` variable,
- and rewrite the code using try/except,

like this:

```
import datetime

_format = "%Y-%m-%d"
l1 = [
    ['2018-04-16', '2020-04-16', 'ANNOVAR_DATE'],
    ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ANNOVAR_DATE']
]

for ele in l1:
    for i in ele:
        try: 
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(i, _format)
            print(f"{i} is the correct date string format.")
        except ValueError:
            print(f"{i} is the incorrect date string format.")
```

then the result is following:

```
2018-04-16 is the correct date string format.
2020-04-16 is the correct date string format.
ANNOVAR_DATE is the incorrect date string format. 
abcd is the incorrect date string format. 
efgh is the incorrect date string format. 
ANNOVAR_DATE is the incorrect date string format.
```

**EDIT:**

For your particular purpose of checking, if there is any date format in list, you can use a counter like this:

```
import datetime

_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
l1 = [
    ['2018-04-16', '2020-04-16', 'ANNOVAR_DATE'],
    ['abcd', 'efgh', 'ANNOVAR_DATE']
]

for ele in l1:
    dt_counter = 0
    
    for i in ele:
        try: 
            dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(i, _format)
            dt_counter += 1
            
        except ValueError:
            pass
        
    
    if dt_counter > 0:
        print(f'There is datetime format in the following list: {ele}')
```

The result will be following:

```
There is datetime format in the following list: ['2018-04-16', '2020-04-16', 'ANNOVAR_DATE']
```

Comment: That works mostly, But What I want is to print out: ['2018-04-16', '2020-04-16', 'ANNOVAR_DATE'] is correct. by using print(ele), however, if I do so, it will come out: ['2018-04-16', '2020-04-16', 'ANNOVAR_DATE']
['2018-04-16', '2020-04-16', 'ANNOVAR_DATE']
['2018-04-16', '2020-04-16', 'ANNOVAR_DATE'] is the incorrect date string format. any ideas?

Comment: @CHANGLINYANG I edited my answer. Is it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to wrap the below with `try/except`

```
datetime.datetime.strptime(i, format)
```

If an exception is raised you will know that there is no match between the string and the format

Comment: if strptime(i, format), it will compare every i in the sublist. However, if it compares format with ANNOVAR_DATE in the list ['2018-04-16', '2020-04-16', 'ANNOVAR_DATE'], code will raise errors and determine ['2018-04-16', '2020-04-16', 'ANNOVAR_DATE'] is the incorrect date string format. But since this sublist contains 2020-04-16, this sublist should be treat as a list that contains correct date format. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The error: `ValueError: time data '2018-04-16' does not match format '%Y-%m-d'` occurs because you forgot the `%` at `d`

change your `format` to `format = "%Y-%m-%d"`

Comment: ValueError: time data 'ANNOVAR_DATE' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'

Answer (score 0):

As others said, there was a type in format value but you need a try-except to manage the wrong format date, besides, using `next()` + `filter()` should be fast and efficient:

```
import datetime

l1 = [['asd'], ['2018-04-16', '2020-04-16', 'ANNOVAR_DATE'],['abcd', 'efgh', 'ANNOVAR_DATE']]

DATE_FORMAT = "%Y-%m-%d"

def has_date_format(sublist):
    for value in sublist:
        try:
            datetime.datetime.strptime(value, DATE_FORMAT)        
            return True
        except: pass
    return False

sublist = next(filter(has_date_format, l1))

if sublist:
    print('Sublist with date format found: ', sublist)
else:
    print('No sublist with date format found ')
```